# How to open web links from some Google Maps markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, marker

I can open web link from marker by

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
window.open('http://example.com/');
});
```

But what if I need to place 100 markers with 100 links to Google Maps? 
My array with coordinates and links looks like this

```
var point = [[52.7081444444445, 58.6677361111111, "Sib/2377/index.html"],
[52.7039611111111, 58.668425, "Sib/2378/index.html"],
[52.6993166666667, 58.6680305555556, "Sib/2379/index.html"],
[52.6946277777778, 58.6679416666667, "Sib/2380/index.html"],
[52.6947833333333, 58.6755555555556, "Sib/2381/index.html"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

add the URL as a property of the marker (`.url`).  Open the window using `this.url`

```
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    var point = points[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: point[0],
        lng: point[1]
      },
      map: map,
      url: point[2]
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      window.open(this.url);
    });
  }
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/df6wbkou/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {
      lat: -33.9,
      lng: 151.2
    }
  });
  setMarkers(map);
}

// Data for the markers consisting of a Latitude, a Longitude and a URL.
var points = [
  [52.7081444444445, 58.6677361111111, "http://www.google.com"],
  [52.7039611111111, 58.668425, "http://www.yahoo.com"],
  [52.6993166666667, 58.6680305555556, "http://maps.google.com"],
  [52.6946277777778, 58.6679416666667, "http://maps.google.com?q=52.6946277777778,58.6679416666667"],
  [52.6947833333333, 58.6755555555556, "http://maps.google.com?q=52.6947833333333,58.6755555555556"]
];

function setMarkers(map) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  // Adds markers to the map.
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    var point = points[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: point[0],
        lng: point[1]
      },
      map: map,
      url: point[2]
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      window.open(this.url);
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: If this answered your question, please [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)